# How to add icons to Jenkins Blue-Ocean Pipelines Stages and Parameters form?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

How can we make visual updates to the Pipelines and Parameter forms?

## Pipeline

- I'd like to add visual representation on each of the steps

  - Maybe add an icon to the descriptions
  - Show the stage names in **bold** or other ways to highlight

[image: screen shot 2018-10-31 at 3 16 33 pm]

## Parameters form

- Each of the form descriptions are very hard to read as the list of parameters grow.

[image: screen shot 2018-10-31 at 3 16 33 pm]

## Questions

- Is it possible to add images?
- Is it possible to add icons or bold text to the pipeline stages?
- It it possible to add icons or bold text to the parameters form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Workaround with Caveat

- There's no simple plugin that supports formatting the blue-ocean pipeline stages and form.
- I could add icons to both the Pipeline Stage names and Parameters form  using unicode characters and it actually gives a visual aid to all the values.

This is NOT a complete solution but a nice workaround for our requirements: using the unicode emojis in the values. Since Java Strings supports unicode values in Strings, Jenkins can handle the values properly.

I used the site https://emojipedia.org to select which values to use. For instance, the value for https://emojipedia.org/ship/ is .

The only **caveat** is that emojis have a different visual representation on different devices as described at emojipedia.org.

## Jenkins Pipeline with Icons

[image: screen shot 2018-11-02 at 5 22 02 pm]

## Jenkins Parameters form with Icons

[image: screen shot 2018-11-02 at 5 22 17 pm]

Comment: Hi, nice workaround!
Could you please add some snippets/examples?

Comment: @Vano here's the snippet https://gist.github.com/marcellodesales/edb951742ee344de70340809333f790a